# Manage access of the connected app to the force.com on behalf of user

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps

Where is stored information that user grants for connected application to access force.com.
After user grants for connected app on following question : 
    "An application would like to connect to your SalesForce.com " where is that stored ?

As I can see it is not in cookie. When I remove all of the force.com cookies, connected app is still in position to access force.com on behalf of the specific user. That is stored in database or somewhere ? How I can (as an user) to manage this to prohibit further access for some connected application that I granted before to access force.com?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `Setup | Personal Information > Personal > Advanced User Details` Here you will get a list of all applications to which you have granted access to your information. In `OAuth Connected App`, you can **revoke** access for an application.

Admins can control the duration of access for a given connected app - go to `Setup | Administration Setup | Manage Apps | Connected Apps` and click on an app. From [the docs](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=connected_app_manage_edit.htm&siteLang=en_US):

> `Require Users to Log In` specifies how frequently a user must log in to
>   maintain the permissions their client application needs from the
>   connected app. You may specify that they only need to log in the first
>   time they use the app, every time they use it, after a certain period
>   of inactivity, or after a certain period of time.

Comment: Thank you, is there time out for these data or they are lifetime ?

Comment: Admins can control the duration of access - see the edit I just made to responsive's answer.